# Changelog/Release notes in NuGet Manager Azure DevOps/VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, devops, nuget-server, azure-artifacts

I'm starting to work more and more with NuGet Manager / NuGet artifact in Azure DevOps and I'm wondering if there is a way to get more information on the nuget pane? We keep track of our changes in a readme.md would like the information from that file to be visible on the NuGet pane?

[image]

Comment: Did you refer to the documentation on publishing nuget packages to review how to set the description?

Comment: Yeah, but I'm asking for more than simply filling in the description tag in the nuspec file. I was hoping for description/release notes/documentation taken from a markdown file and shown on the image.

Comment: The description field is what's available. You can populate it with whatever information you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Artifacts shows most of the well-known metadata that each package type offers. Have you considered using the [releaseNotes field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#releasenotes)?

If/when the NuGet team implements README.md files as a convention ([discussed but not scheduled](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Package-README.md-support#next-steps)), we will update Artifacts to display the README.md on the package page.